# c# designer code error when debug

Tags: c#

I have a solution in VS 2013 C#, it raises an error when I debug it, when I build it has no errors, it is a visual component error, error is check "if the object is null...","ue the new keyword..." here is the code where raise the error:

```
 public static void smethod_11()
{
    int num = 1;
    Color white1 = System.Drawing.Color.White;   
    do
    {
        Class9.panel_0[num].Controls["FnzProduct_" + Conversions.ToString(num)].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        Class9.panel_0[num].Controls["FnzProduct_" + Conversions.ToString(num)].BackgroundImage = null;
        Class9.panel_0[num].Controls["FnzID_" + Conversions.ToString(num)].Text = string.Empty;
        Class9.panel_0[num].Controls["FnzVolume_" + Conversions.ToString(num)].Text = " ";
        Class9.panel_0[num].Controls["FnzAmount_" + Conversions.ToString(num)].Text = " ";
        Class9.panel_0[num].Controls["FnzPrice_" + Conversions.ToString(num)].Text = " ";
        Class9.panel_0[num].Controls["FnzStatus_" + Conversions.ToString(num)].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        Class9.panel_0[num].BackColor = Color.LightSlateGray;
        Class9.panel_0[num].Show();
        Class9.gclass0_0[num].Value = 0;
        num++;
    }
```

and here is class9 code:

```
 internal static Panel[] panel_0 = new Panel[0x21];
```

How to correct it?

Comment: How to correct it?? Debug It. Check if Class9.panel_0[num] is not null for all provided num values.

Comment: Do you ever set `panel_0[num] = something;` ?

Comment: no didn't set to something what shall I set, true, 1 ?

Comment: found it I code in vb but is the same had to make array for values

Comment: thank you I have solved it : internal static int[,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,] arr1 = new int[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
    internal static Panel[] panel_0 = new Panel[arr1[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]];